# v-data-table now displaying data or headers in Vue3 and Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 running on vite and using vuetify. I am trying to display my data table with values but it does not even show headers that supposedly static and defined in my script section.

```
<div v-if="marketdata.asks">
      <div>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex md lg>
            <v-card-title>Asks</v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
              dense
              :sort-by="['price']"
              :sort-desc="[true]"
              disable-pagination
              hide-default-footer
              :headers="asksHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.asks"
              :items-per-page="5"
            >
              <template v-slot:header.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:header.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:header.relamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }"> {{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>

              <!-- For highlighting my orders, TODO need a price:uuid array before grouping by price in AppTraderview   -->
              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ Number(Math.round(item.price+'e8')+'e-8') }}
<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template
                v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.maxvolume+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
              <template
                v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }"
              >{{ Number(Math.round(item.price*item.maxvolume+'e8')+'e-8') }}</template>
            </v-data-table>
```

This is my script section with my headers defined, This is only part of my code both above and below

```
export default {
  name: "MarketData",
  props: ['wallets', 'marketdata', 'myOrdersThisMarket'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      cexprice: "",
      myOrders: "",
      takerDialog: false,
      makerDialog: false,
      activeCoins: [],
      walletBalance: { base: 0, rel: 0 },
      trade: { base: "", rel: "", price: "", amount: "0" },
      appName: "MarketData",
      customerrors: [],
      asksHeaders: [
        {
          text: "Price (rel)",
          align: "left",
          sortable: true,
          value: "price"
        },
        { text: "Amount (base)", align: "left", value: "maxvolume" },
        { text: "Total (rel))", align: "right", value: "relamount" }
      ],
      bidsHeaders: [
        {
          text: "Price (rel)",
          align: "left",
          sortable: true,
          value: "price"
        },
        { text: "Base Amount", align: "left", value: "baseamount" },
        { text: "Can Cancel", align: "right", value: "maxvolume" }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Have you included the [labs components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/)? No VDataTable without it at the moment

Comment: I did the following it does display the data now but not the columns and headings though:
`import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default {
  name: "MarketData",
  props: ['wallets', 'marketdata', 'myOrdersThisMarket'],
  components: {
    VDataTable
  },`

Comment: If you don't see headers and columns, what data is left to see? Can you provide a [playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/)?

Comment: Hard to make a playground however here is the project link itself:

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/RICK/MORTY

The component is AtomicDex OrderBook which is in question here

Comment: Use [{title: '', key: ''}] as headers items for vuetify v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the link, now I understand the issue. Seems to be two things:

- You are setting the column header title in the `text` property, but in Vuetify 3, that was changed to [`title`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ba964822a5b50418fdef505c47432da39e894013/packages/vuetify/src/labs/VDataTable/types.ts#L11).
- Similarly, the `header.<column name>` slots were renamed to [`column.<column name>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-%5B%60column.%7Bstring%7D%60%5D), so `v-slot:header.price` now is `v-slot:column.price`

If you update the names, it should work again.

Comment: Thanks mate works perfect now, any tips to disable pagination and enable horizontal scroll ? much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to set `:items-per-page` to -1 to show all items on the same page. Then you can remove the pagination by setting an empty `footer` slot. Horizontal scroll should get activated when you limit the height of the component. Does that work?

Comment: It does not work unfortunately